# (R)I can't import other libaries to my R package

Tags: r, import, package, roxygen2

My goal is to make it unnecessary to type "library(ggplot2)" and "library(grid)" after installing my package(named wcp1108). But still I had to type in. Description and Namespace file is as below.
Could I know what should be fixed?

```
[Description] : the ggplot2 and grid is already in the imports 

Package: wcp1108
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person(given = "First",
           family = "Last",
           role = c("aut", "cre"),
           email = "first.last@example.com",
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: `use_mit_license()`, `use_gpl3_license()` or friends to pick a
        license
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
Imports: ggplot2, grid
NeedsCompilation: no
Packaged: 2020-11-08 11:19:45 UTC; id0101
Author: First Last [aut, cre] (YOUR-ORCID-ID)
Maintainer: First Last <first.last@example.com>


[Namespace]
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
export(wcp)
```

Comment: The use of `Depends:` and `Imports:` makes those packages seamlessly available to the functions in your package, not to the user who loads your package. If you want to know how to make them available, look at the `tidyverse` meta-package. (I don't think it's as easy as changes to this file.)

Comment: You have an `Imports:` in `DESCRIPTION` but no corresponding `import(...)` or `importFrom()` in `NAMESPACE`.  Add that, and you should be fine.